# Using PyEval_EvalCode in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm trying to port an extension module from 2.7 to 3.5.  The extension module uses `PyEval_EvalCode`.  It does this with some code similar to the following:

```
struct _node *compiled_node = PyParser_SimpleParseString (in_string, Py_file_input);
if (compiled_node)
{
    PyCodeObject *compiled_code = PyNode_Compile (compiled_node, "temp.py");
    if (compiled_code)
    {
      return_value.Reset(PyEval_EvalCode (compiled_code, globals.get(), locals.get()));
    }
}
```

In Python 2.7 this works fine.  In Python 3.5 I get a compilation failure, because `PyNode_Compile` returns a `PyCodeObject`, but in Python 3.5 `PyEval_EvalCode` *accepts* a `PyObject*`.  What do I need to do to convert this into a `PyObject` that I can pass to `PyEval_EvalCode`?

Answer (score 4):

For the vast majority of Python types, `PyObject` is the "parent" struct of the type. Try casting the argument: `(PyObject*)compiled_code`.

The [Code Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/code.html) docs make it clear that `PyObject*` can be `PyCodeObject*` (otherwise `PyCode_Check` wouldn't exist), so if you know it's a code object, the cast is safe.

Comment: Thanks, it's weird that they decided to have `PyNode_Compile` return a `PyCodeObject` instead of a `PyObject` like all the other methods do.  That threw me for a loop.